# Taking information from ListBox and putting it into a label 

Tags: vb6

Basically I've got a `ListBox` in this Visual Basic (VB6) application I'm writing. The `ListBox` contains "Movies Watched."

I want to be able to grab all the items in this ListBox, and put those items into a label. But I can't quite figure out how to get the information from my ListBox to my label.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code and explain where you are having difficulties?

Comment: It's for VB6. I haven't really tried much because I'm pretty lost, haha. I've got my listbox built with my information.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim ListText As String
Dim Counter As Integer

ListText = ""

For Counter = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    If List1.Selected(Counter) = True Then
        ListText = ListText & List1.List(Counter) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next

MsgBox ListText
```

Answer (score 1):

This will take everything from the ListBox and add it to a Label as you asked in your question. If you want to just put the Selected Items into your label use SpectralGhost's answer.

```
Dim x As Integer
List1.AddItem ("Hello")
List1.AddItem ("World")

For x = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption + List1.List(x) + vbCrLf
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB, so I can't give you any code.

Just run throught all of the items and do `myLabel.Content = myLabel.Content + myListBox.Items[i].Text`.